# For loop in javascript giving error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using for loop. Function is working but it is also throwing error in console.

```
$('input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var visible = $('ul').find('li span').filter(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                return this
            }
        }).get();
        console.log(visible.length)
        for (i = 0; visible.length; i++) {
            console.log(visible[i].id)
        }
    }
})
```

**Body**

```
<input type="text" />
<ul>
  <li> <span id="one">one</span> </li>
  <li> <span id="two">two</span> </li>
  <li> <span id="three" style="display:none">two</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: -1 for unreadable code.

Comment: Have you read the error which is showing up in the console?

Comment: if you ident your code you would see the extra `})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
for(i=0; visible.length;i++ ){
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < visible.length;i++){
```

Comment: to `for(var i = 0, l = visible.length; i < l; ++i) {`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice way to do it correctly:

```
$('input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        var $visible = $('ul').find('li span').filter(function () {
            return $(this).css('display') != 'none';
        }).get();

        console.log($visible.length);

        $.each($visible, function (index, value) {
            console.log($(value)[0].id);
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jTm4S/)